# Не работает отключение паузы у видео при сворачивании вкладки

Tags: html, html5, google-chrome, видео

Хочу написать код для собственных часов, но появилась проблема.

Я написал часть кода, который автоматически воспроизводит зараннее "заткнутое" (по звуку) видео, и который ДОЛЖЕН делать так, чтобы пауз при сворачивании окна не происходило.

```
<div class="video-container">
    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline preload="auto" id="back_video">
        <source src="video/back.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
</div>
```

Как можно заметить, в коде указан параметр *playsinline*, который как раз и должен отключить паузу у видео, но этого не происходит.

Поясняю подробнее: загрузка видео происходит безукоризненно, и циклично, НО при переходе на другую вкладку, а потом на обратно на вкладку с видео оказывается, что оно всё время находилось в паузе.

Уже перепробовал по разному переставлять параметры видео, писал даже простой JS-скрипт:

```
if (video.paused) {
   video.play()
}
```

...но и это тоже не помогло.

Вожусь с этим уже неделю, так и не пойму в чём дело.

Остаётся надежда только на вас. Я уже реально задолбался ***искать исправления проблемы и видеть их неработоспособность***.